# plot many lines

Tags: pstricks, memory, pst-plot

I have generated pstricks-code from data:

```
\psset{unit=10cm}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(1,1)
    \psline(0.22029880495812262,0.23497192515414284)(0.21975600857793104,0.23394684903842253)
    \psline(0.2584529413334904,0.22000887379324077)(0.2551267563022901,0.21319288260584074)
    \psline(0.2584529413334904,0.22000887379324077)(0.2591309918937222,0.22175303315432685)
    \psline(0.3833672951833354,0.13344349076667328)(0.38201653304384925,0.13337464237083807)
    \psline(0.574041875405995,0.2843744740747551)(0.5783130600368138,0.2848105139150266)
    \psline(0.574041875405995,0.2843744740747551)(0.5708758597984268,0.28412967977846876)
    \psline(0.5611001859745068,0.3016936705374795)(0.5624740836974276,0.30102813604442846)
    \psline(0.5611001859745068,0.3016936705374795)(0.5599451864639463,0.30213736019950443)
    \psline(0.33774570434501133,0.15330242805342456)(0.336387823564517,0.15383026575480516)
    \psline(0.22830905580127048,0.252222273221032)(0.22817380162135673,0.25358394149416136)
    % about 9000 more lines
\end{pspicture}
```

But LaTeX gives me an out of memory error.

Is there any better (less memory consuming) way to create this plot of about 9000 small lines (two coordinates each)?

---

The data can be downloaded here: https://paste.ee/p/q08ru (Format: x0,y0 x1,y1)

Comment: Looks like an exported code from a Programm. Nobody needs so many decimals ... can you provide the complete data for a download?

Comment: https://paste.ee/p/q08ru      Format:  x0,y0    x1,y1

Comment: are you trying to plot a city map with pstricks? Maybe this is not the right place to ask this... but how did you get all those points?

Comment: (by the way, judging by how small the distance between points are, I think you can get away trying to plot the points themselves instead of the lines, and it will be visually very similar)

Comment: Yes, indeed. It's a very small part of a map. Plotting the lines like Herbert did works if the lines are very short but makes visible breaks to the roads when they are longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lines are really short and it makes more sense to use the 
plot style `dots`:

```
    \documentclass[pstricks,border=10pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pst-plot}
    \begin{document}

    \psset{unit=10} 
    \readdata\Data{pstricks.data}
    \begin{pspicture}(-0.1,-0.1)(1.1,1.1)
    \psaxes[Dx=0.2,Dy=0.2,labelFontSize=\scriptstyle]{->}(1,1.05)
    \listplot[plotstyle=dots,dotsize=1pt]{\Data}
    \end{pspicture}
    \end{document}
```

If you still need the lines then you have to increase the TeX input 
buffer or to create a solution on PostScript level.

And here a solution which needs the data file *without* a comma 
between the coordinates (can simply be replaced by a space).

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=10} 
\makeatletter
\begin{pspicture}(-0.1,-0.1)(1,1)
\psaxes[Dx=0.2,Dy=0.2,labelFontSize=\scriptstyle]{->}(0.8,0.8)
\pscustom{
  \code{
  [ (pstricks.data) run ] /Points exch def  % save data
  Points length 4 div cvi /No exch def      % No of lines
  1 setlinewidth
  1 0 0 setrgbcolor
  0 4 No { 
    /iNo exch def
    Points iNo 4  getinterval aload pop 
    \tx@ScreenCoor
    4 2 roll \tx@ScreenCoor
    moveto lineto stroke
  } for 
  }
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I already increased the input buffer to TeXLives maximum -- still no success. :-(

Comment: for the above example it works with the default setting.

Comment: I mean I tried to plot the lines (not the dots) -- and it didn't work (even after increasing the memory limit).

Comment: I edited my answer with a solution on PostScript level.

Comment: I just tried it, the file now has the format    x1 y1 x2 y2 (as you mentioned), but with the default toolchain (latex, dvips, ps2pdf) I get a ghostscript error. Is there any hidden pitfall?

Comment: New file: https://paste.ee/p/7rOE2

Comment: that is the same file I used. You need `ps2pdf -dNOSAFER <file>.ps`. GhostScript wont run external files (the data file in this case) if not set. Or run xelatex

Comment: It works. I LOVE IT!

Comment: Can I modify the linecap in postscript? I guess round linecaps (c-c) would close the cracks in the lines.

Comment: Write a line after `setrgbcolor` with:  `2 setlinecap` or use value `1` (rounded)

Comment: It works like a charm with value `1` -- such a nice map now. You truly are the heart of the community, herbert!